# Reflections and multiple jars

Tags: java, reflection, jar, classloader, reflections

I got two jar files, lets call them `domain.jar` and `scanner.jar`. In the scanner jar I have used Reflections library like so:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder().addUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage(packageName)).setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false)));
Set<Class<?>> subTypesOf = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

where if I point the `packageName` to packages inside the scanner.jar everything works fine, but if I try to find classes from the `domain.jar` it always returns empty set.

I run it with `java -cp domain.jar -jar scanner.jar`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? From Reflections usage [examples](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/wiki/UseCases) it supports multimodule projects so this should be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-cp` and `-jar` options are mutually exclusive. Either you use `-jar`, and the classpath is composed from the jar file and all the other jar files referenced in its manefest, or you use `-cp` and list all the jars that must be part of the classpath.

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) about the -jar option says:

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

So, try with

```
java -cp domain.jar;scanner.jar your.fully.qualified.MainClass
```